# input field target is null while accessing in onChange field in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Even if I am assigning value to name and value fields, event.target is getting as null. 
event.target.value is getting value but not any other.

```
    <input type= "text" 
       name= {value}
       value = {currentValue}
       onChange = { (e) => this.onInputChanged(e) } 
       disabled = { disabled }
    />

    onInputChanged = async (e) => {
       await this.setState({ currentValue: e.target.value })
       console.log('event', e.target);    //This is showing null
       this.props.onInputChange(e);
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to post some code

Comment: you need to set the value to get value share some of your codebase where you are struggling

Answer (score 14, accepted):

React reuses the synthetic event object so you can't use it in an async context as it is.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling):

> The `SyntheticEvent` is pooled. This means that the `SyntheticEvent`
>   object will be reused and **all properties will be nullified after the
>   event callback has been invoked**. This is for performance reasons. As
>   such, **you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way**.
>
> **Note**:
>
> If you want to access the event properties in an asynchronous way, you
>   should call `event.persist()` on the event, which will remove the
>   synthetic event from the pool and allow references to the event to be
>   retained by user code.

You either need to extract the information synchronously or call `event.persist()` to persist the object before using it in an async context.

Extracting the value synchronously:

```
onInputChanged = event => {
   const value = event.target.value;
   (async () => {
       await this.setState({ currentValue: value });
       this.props.onInputChange(e);
   })();           
}
```

Persisting the event before using it in an async context:

```
onInputChanged = event => {
   event.persist();
   (async () => {
       await this.setState({ currentValue: e.target.value });
       console.log('event', e.target);
       this.props.onInputChange(e);
   })();           
}
```

Comment: `this.setState` returns `undefined`, so `await` will only work if you win the race-condition.