# Material React Table simple filtering not working Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filtering, material-react-table

Hello we've been using Material React Table npm package for showing data, but filtering isn't working, so every time I type a letter this error pops out

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
> at MRT_FilterTextField.tsx:119:1
> at later (debounce.js:7:1)

This is the code

```
const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        header: `${t("login_title_email")}`,
        accessorFn: (row) => row.log_email_address,
        enableClickToCopy: true,
        filterVariant: "text", // default
      },
      {
        header: `${t("login_title_ip")}`,
        accessorKey: "login_attempt_ip",
        enableClickToCopy: true,
      },
      {
        header: `${t("login_title_date")}`,
        accessorFn: (row) => new Date(row.log_date),
        filterFn: "greaterThanOrEqualTo",
        sortingFn: "datetime",
        id: "log_date",
        Cell: ({ cell }) => cell.getValue()?.toLocaleDateString(),
        Filter: ({ column }) => (
          <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
            <DatePicker
              onChange={(newValue) => {
                column.setFilterValue(newValue);
              }}
              slotProps={{
                textField: {
                  sx: { minWidth: "120px" },
                  variant: "standard",
                },
              }}
              value={column.getFilterValue()}
            />
          </LocalizationProvider>
        ),
      },
      {
        header: `${t("login_type")}`,
        accessorKey: "log_type",
      },
    ],
    []
  );
 <MaterialTable
            data={logs}
            columns={columns}
            enableColumnOrdering
            enableGrouping
            enablePinning
            enableRowNumbers
            initialState={{
              density: "compact",
              showGlobalFilter: true,
              showColumnFilters: true,
            }}
          />
```

Data structure is like this:

```
const data = [
{log_date: "2023-06-02T04:01:43.665Z"
log_email_address: "test@gmail.com"
log_type: "login_email"
login_attempt_ip: 
"10.10.16.10"
user_id: "12334444"}
]
```

I would appreciate any kind of help to solve the issue :D
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in React version, project has been using React version 17 and React-dom version 16. Apparently event and value inside onChange was always `null` that is why it was throwing error.

> The SyntheticEvent is pooled. This means that the SyntheticEvent
> object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the
> event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As
> such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.

More about this event issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58059004/input-field-target-is-null-while-accessing-in-onchange-field-in-reactjs)

After I upgraded to version

```
 "react": "^18.2.0",   
 "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
```

issue was solved.